# Turn on Chrome Autocomplete on Textarea

Tags: html, autocomplete

I am trying to get a textarea to have autocomplete, the inputs have autocomplete fine, but no matter what combination  I do, Im unable to get it to work fro a textarea.

```
<form id="autocomplete-form" target="sendToblank" action="about:blank" autocomplete="on">
   <textarea name="testautocomplete" id="testautocomplete" rows="1"></textarea>
   <input type="text" id="corporate" name="corporate" />
</form>


$("#autocomplete-form").submit();
```

The above snippit, the input works, The jquery call is a quick way I am submitting a blank form to save it to chrome, it simulates a form post which is what triggers the browser to cache the autocompletes.

Is there a way to get textarea to autocomplete? I have tried adding autocomplete="on" directly to the textarea..

A Chrome extension would also be ok if it wasnt possible natively.

Comment: It should work from Chrome v66
Quote from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete
> v66 - Support added for autocomplete on the <textarea> and <select> elements.

The question is how do you trigger/open the auto-complete dropdown. For input it's arrow down, but that doesn't seem to do anything for textarea